# Many to Many for Dropdown list

Tags: hibernate, jsf-2

I'm a noobie at hibernate / jsf so I'm wondering what the standard way to deal is to deal with the following (fairly standard) scenario is.

I have 2 classes:

```
public Class Appointment
   Client client;
   Date   date;

public Class Client
   String name;
   String address;
```

There is a many to one relationship between appointment and client (client can have lots of appointments). However, when creating an appointment I want the user to be able to select the client from a dropdown list. It seems to me that to do that I need a many to many relationship between appointment and client. Is that the standard method? Are there alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extremly common task. And no, you don't want a many to many, that would mean that the same appointment chould have multiple clients. Try something like:

bean:

```
private Long clientId;
private Date date;
private List<Client> clients;

public List<Client> getClients(){
    if(clients == null){
        clients = clientDAO.findAll(); // Lazy loading since JSF has a habit of calling the getter multiple times.
    }
    return clients;
}

// Getters and setters for client and date

public void saveAppointment(){
    applicationDAO.createAppointment(date, clientId);
}
```

xhtml:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.clientId}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.clients}" var="client" itemLabel="#{client.name]" itemValue="#{client.id}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use only the many to one mapping because only the client can have many appointments, an appointment is specific to a unique client if I get what you want to do. so you have to use the one to many annotation, and don't forget to specify the mappedby property so that your relation could function from the two sides

Good luck and sorry for my english :s

Comment: But to use a dropdown list of clients when creating a new appointment I'm going to need a list of the clients, and the only way to get that (I think) is with a Many to Many relationship, even though the normal relationship is one client to many appointments. This is what I'm not sure of. Anyway, thanks for answering.

Comment: I don't think so, by this way you'll not have a good conception for your project, to pass the list of clients to your dropdown list, you have to instanciate a list of client in your controller an pass it as parameter to your jsp, jsf ... ( depending of the technology you're using, via the resquest parameter, modelattributes or something else depending on what you are using

Comment: I supppose I could create a method in my AppointmentBean that returns a list of all Clients. I'm just wondering what the standard way of dealing with this situation (which I suppose is very common) is.

Comment: Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
  // Create a Hibernate query (HQL)
  Query query = session.getNamedQuery("AppointmentsBean.getAll");
and in your DAO class, you add the named query
@NamedQuery(name="AppointmentsBean.getAll", query="FROM  your_table_name") 
  return  query.list();